# Getting error while uploading a document to a document library in sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

Whenever I activate the content organizer I am getting an error while adding the new document to any document library but if I deactivate it then I can upload the documents.

The error that is coming is :

```
Error : Access Denied
  Current User
  You are currently signed in as : HDC-MSODC2\NA249854
  Sign in as a different user
  Go back to site
```

I've tried everything but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: the current user doesn't have the correct rights so either log in with a different user or get the rights for  HDC-MSODC2\NA249854 sorted out so you have access

Comment: Current user have full control. Actually what's happening is that it is working fine when i deavtivate the content organiser feature at site level but after activating again the error is coming. And i have applied the rules which needs the activation of content organiser. I have also created a content type having document content type as parent. 2 days before it was working fine but after that i dont know what happened it is showing error now i.e. Access Denied error.

Comment: Hello anyone please help me with the above problem. I got stuck due to that problem and i m unable to resolve it.

Comment: please update your question with the missing details. If you leave out so much information how can you expect an answer that fits your situation?

Comment: Actually i was trying to upload the files to their respective folder based on the content types like images in image folder, sourcecodes in source code folder. For image,video,audio and document there is inbuilt content types and no content type for source code so i created the content type named it as sourcecode and then created the rules for automatically storing the files into their destined location. After creating the rules when i tried to upload a file check whether rules are working fine or not then it was coming the error ***Access Denied***